# В чем будет смысловая разница четырёх предложений, состоящих из одних и тех же слов?

Tags: стилистика

У меня тоже есть собака.

У меня тоже собака есть.

Собака у меня тоже есть.

У меня собака тоже есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница будет в смысловом ударении, интонационном (выделяю прописными):

1. У меня ТОЖЕ есть собака (как и у тебя).
2. У МЕНЯ тоже собака есть (не только у тебя).
3. СОБАКА у меня тоже есть (кроме кролика и рыбок).
4. У меня собака тоже ЕСТЬ (ты плохо слышишь? есть, говорю! волкодав!).